# Hard disk for SharePoint 2013 Server in a two-tier Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, hardware

Microsoft recommends a minimum 80GB of disk space for System drive (C:) for a SharePoint Server 2013 (Web+App Server). doesn't that affect system availability in the future.

Comment: Thank you.
So if i consider a second drive with 60 GB, for SharePoint log files is it enough? Also for SQL Server, MS recommendes 80GB for system drive.

Comment: that will be fine but for SQL again same thing dont use the system drive for SQL LDF and MDF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is minimum requirement for the system drive. But as a practice you have to make sure none of these stored on the c drive.

- ULS logs as these will fill the drive quickly
- IIS logs
- Usage Logs.
- Index location

If you store everything on C drive then yes you environment will be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

**Hardware requirements—web servers, application servers, and single server installations**
The values in the following table are **minimum values** for installations on a single server with a built-in database and for web and application servers that are running SharePoint 2013 in a multiple server farm installation. For information about the deployment types that are used in this table
For all installation scenarios, **you must have sufficient hard disk space for the base installation and sufficient space for diagnostics such as logging**, **debugging, creating memory dumps**, and so on. **For production use, you must also have additional free disk space for day-to-day operations**. **In addition, maintain two times as much free space as you have RAM for production environments.**

[image]